# ASIHTTPRequest working on emulator but not iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, protocols, asihttprequest

Hey guys I have done lots of work with ASIHTTPRequest so far and use it several times in my ios application, however in one area of my app where I have added another asihttprequest method its not working properly.

First of all it must be said that the reason I'm trying to spread the load of downloading and parsing the data.. If I do this on the subview it takes a good 2-3 second to go through the second xml sheet and get all of the related values out.. where as If I do it on this mainview where people are not seeing anything load etc then when the go back to the subview it should look almost instant. I don't know how correct this is but I figure its a okay thing to do to make the app feel abit snappier.

So I am setting it the asihttprequest methods identically as the other ones that work minus caching.

What happens is I select a table cell from the main view that loads the second view and parses a bunch of info to the tableview. the User then selects a value which is passed back to the main view and displayed.

I then parse another lot of xml data checking the selected valueID against everything in the second xml sheet. so that when the user selects the second cell I pass all the data that was just parsed over to the second view to make it look as though its loaded alot faster.

Heres a flow chart of that will explain what I'm trying to do abit better
[image]

This is what the parser code looks like in the main view which is the one thats working in the emulator but not on the iphone.

This is my protocol that I call from the subview and pass all the values I need to over and fire off the request to the mainviews ASIHTTPRequest.

```
    - (void) setManufactureSearchFields:(NSArray *)arrayValues withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myIndexPath
    {
        manufactureSearchObjectString = [[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"] objectAtIndex:0];
        manufactureIdString = [[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUID"] objectAtIndex:0]; //Restricts Models dataset
        manufactureResultIndexPath = myIndexPath;
        [self.tableView reloadData]; //reloads the tabels so you can see the value in the tableViewCell.
        //need some sort of if statment here so that if the back button is pressed modelSearchObjectString is not changed..

        if (oldManufactureSearchObjectString != manufactureSearchObjectString) {
            modelResultIndexPath = NULL;
            modelSearchObjectString = @"empty";
            oldManufactureSearchObjectString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:manufactureSearchObjectString];
        }
//These two lines below are what execute ASIHTTPRequest and set up my parser etc
        dataSetToParse = @"ICMod"; // This sets the if statment inside parserDidEndDocument
        [self setRequestString:@"ICMod.xml"]; //Sets the urlstring for XML inside setRequestString

    }
```

This then fires the ASIHTTPRequest delegate methods.

```
- (IBAction)setRequestString:(NSString *)string
{
    //Set database address
    //NSMutableString *databaseURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/codeData/"]; // imac development
    NSMutableString *databaseURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/codeData/"]; // iphone development

    //PHP file name is being set from the parent view
    [databaseURL appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"%@", databaseURL);

    //call ASIHTTP delegates (Used to connect to database)
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:databaseURL];

    //This sets up all other request
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}
```

When I run this through debug with break points while testing on the iphone this is where the app falls over.. but On the emulator it has no problems.

This next method never gets called when testing on the iphone but workds sweet on the emulator.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{   
        responseString = [request responseString]; //Pass requested text from server over to NSString 
        capturedResponseData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

        [self startTheParsingProcess:capturedResponseData];
}
```

This is the only other delegate that is fired when testing on the iphone, sends me an alret saying the connection has timed out.

```
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"A connection failure occurred." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
```

I don't think you need to see all the parser delegates as I don't think they are the issue as this is where the app falls over...

here is what gets printed to the log...

```
2011-11-29 14:38:08.348 code[1641:707] http://000.000.000.000:0000/codeData/second.xml
2011-11-29 14:38:18.470 code[1641:707] Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=2 "The request timed out" UserInfo=0x1e83a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out}
```

If you need more of my code let me know.. but I'm at abit of a loss here as like I say there is no difference to how Im doing this ASIHTTPRequest to other views other than I'm initializing it from the protocol that I'm setting up from the second view.. maybe I should set the values before I reload the table or something... I'm not sure though hopefully someone can help me out with this one and spot the issue I cannot see.

Comment: Are you running a web server on your iPhone? Before you had a different address, but you changed it to http://127.0.0.1:8888.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you view 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/codeData/' with Safari on the iPhone? Chances are that server isn't available from whatever networks the iPhone is connected to.

If your iMac is using DCHP it is possible that the address has changed since you originally set the value.

Comment: Okay so was half way through typing out a reply to you when I had this realisation.. thinking I was being smart I turned on my firewall this morning... first time I have done this on my mac.. little did I know it would mess up my sharing IP of this computer.. ARRRRRRRRRR annoying.. the emulator worked because it is the computer.. the iphone didnt work because its trying to access the shared file on this computer over the wifi which was not happening because of my firewall! DAMNIT! lol but thank you so much for the idea to test through safari.. thats what made me click to the firewall etc.

Comment: I'd suggest two changes to make your development life easier. One, make the address you connect to editable from the iPhone app (even if only in debug build) and two, use a Bonjour (i.e. .local) address if you can.

Comment: the ipaddress I am using is the one that you can find in the system prefrences > sharing > websharing.. which has the ip address you can use over a wireless network for testing.. Thanks for the suggestion though checking it out now.

Comment: Look at the top of the same sharing panel at the computer name setting where it says: "Computers on your local network can access your computer at: foo.local"

Comment: perfect.. thanks for that! :P still pretty new to this stuff but learning more and more everyday specially with the help of this awesome community!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the case correct on the URL? The simulator is much more forgiving on case-sensitivity than the actual device.

Comment: yep. its correct, just double checked it... was really hoping that it was wrong.. damnit.

Answer (score 0):

Do not fly blind but use an HTTP Proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for making sure your requests are actually fired and result into what you expect.

Comment: okay just checking the link you sent me know, thanks for the suggestion.